# Cannot access admin if setting is set and cannot acces website if setting is not set

Tags: django, linux, nginx, supervisord

I have a Django website in production so DEBUG = False

There is a setting:
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

If it is set to True then I can access the admin and log in, but then I cannot access the website itself and I get a bad gateway error. If the setting is missing or set to False then I can access the website fine but I cannot log into admin. A bit confusing

Here are the settings related to domains and CSRF:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS =  ["localhost","102.219.85.91","founderslooking.com","app.founderslooking.com"]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://127.0.0.1",
    "http://localhost:file",
    "http://app.founderslooking.com",
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None

SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "founderslooking.com"

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost", "http://*.127.0.0.1", "http://app.founderslooking.com",]

INTERNAL_IPS = [
    "127.0.0.1",
]
```

First time I deploy a Django site so not sure what the settings should be for production. Thanks

I see this error in the NginX log:

```
*611 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream,
```

I now notice that if I am not logged in on the admin side that I can access the website fine but I cannot access the login path for the front.

Comment: whether your production url using SSL?.  I think SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE works correctly only under the HTTPS

Comment: Ok so I really must have SSL enabled on the domain for this to work properly because whether or not that setting is setting I cannot access admin and the site at the same time.

Comment: So your issue is when SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True, admin is working and site is not. And  when SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False, admin is not working but site is working.